# view with nested partial having different models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which has a partial view on  it. In the view i am using a model, i would like to know if in the partial view on this page. I would like to have two different model for the partial and but i would like the partial to load the data into the view from the database. *Is this possible and what is the best way of doing this?* The partial should return a List model and the view should have a model. The partial is nested on a view.

```
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult getChapterList(int subjectID)
      {
         // DATA LOADED FORM DATABASE
          return PartialView("");
      }
```

Comment: you have one main view then one model for main view two model for your partial?

Comment: There are numerous ways to achieve this. For example, use a view model containing 2 properties, one for the object and one for the collection of objects, or use `@Html.Action()` to call a method that returns the collection as a partial.